# php variable copy in loop strange behaivor

Tags: php

Good day. Faced a problem that looks somehow like this:
I have a variable, that in loop is reset and refilled. I assign that variable to other variable as it's property(Like $item->subitems). 
Ater that I collect $item to an array of $items for example.
Each loop this variable is re-set and re-filled, and contains different data.
Approximate sample code goes below:

```
<?php
$seasons = array(1,2);
$ltabs= array(1);
$all = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
        foreach ($ltabs as $tab)
        {
            //Resetting an object instance
            $itm=false;
            //Re-Initing object
            if (1==1)
            {
                $itm->height = 1;
                $itm->width  = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                $itm->height = 3;
                $itm->width  = 4;
            }
            //And thats where crap happens
            //foreach($seasons as $season) //Dont work that way too
            for ($y=0;$y<count($seasons);$y++)
            {
                //Re-initing local array for needed values
                $itemz=array();
                //$itm->items = array();
                for($a=0;$a < count($all);$a++) {
                    if ($all[$a] % $seasons)//Not tested, supposed to gove ANY dofference in arrays. 
                    {
                        $itemz[]=$all[$a];
                    }
                 }
                $itm->items = $itemz;
                $rtabs[$season] = $itm;
                unset($itemz);
                //unset($itemz);
            }
        }
        //Returns crap.
        var_dump($rtabs);
?>
```

But when I try to

```
<?php
foreach($rtabs as $itm)
{
    var_dump($itm->items);
}
?>
```

I see that all these subitems contain same set of data.
I have sucseeded to defeat it only by re-assigning whole $itm variable in this sub-loop. But I'd like to undeerstand - why does it acts that way?..
According to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch02_03.htm) article - garbage collector and php's  copy-on-write thing should be initialised when I've resetted this $itemz array, so to me all this looks quite unlogickal.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does your sample reproduce the error? if not, please reduce your real code until you only have the code left that makes what you describe happen. In the process of doing so, 99% chance that you'll discover what is causing it because you're not scrutinizing your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, objects are copied by reference, so on this line:

```
$rtabs[$season] = $itm;
```

you're not placing a copy of the `$itm` object into your array - you're copying a reference to it. When you later change the original object, the version in the `rtabs` array gets changed too.

If you want to make a separate copy, you need to do something like this.

```
$rtabs[$season] = clone $itm;
```

Comment: Can't vote-up, but thanks. Explained well. marked as an answer.